# Django how make makemigrations and migrate when making changes at models

Tags: python, django

Whenever I make changes to the models (and subsequently to the views) when I do `makemigrations` or `migration`, I always run into problems. Sometimes running `makemigrations` django notices the changes, but then when I run the command `migrate` django writes that there are no changes to be made. Other times, dozens of `exceptions` are generated during `makemigrations`. Django writes that he does not find certain `tables` or certain `fields` but I read that the errors report the names before my changes.

The only solution to all this is to delete content of:

```
_pycache_
views.py
sql3.db3 database
```

Leave only `models.py`. At this point I can proceed with the `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands.

The question: is there an easier way? What am I wrong?

Comment: migrations are about changes to models, changes to views should not affect them in any way.

Comment: can you add some specific errors that you are getting. The one that you mentioned is django unable to detect changes can be because of the app not being added in settings.py in installed_apps

Comment: yes i know. but if I don't delete the views it generates errors because the functions in here use the model names before editing

Comment: Which errors are you keep getting ?

Comment: For example in a app 'auctions' where I've model 'obj' django wrote 'auctions_obj' no such of table. Or in a table Obj with a field 'name' wrote obj_name no such of field. The values that django can't  found (table 'obj or field 'name') are the old name before changes in models.py. It is as if django read the old models and not the new models present in models.py. In fact, if I delete everything (including db) django returns to work with updated names